# Passing command line unicode argument to Java code

Tags: java, unicode, command-line-arguments

I have to pass command line argument which is Japanese to Java main method. If I type Unicode characters on command-line window, it displays '?????' which is OK, but the value passed to java program is also '?????'. How do I get the correct value of argument passed by the command window? Below is sample program which writes to a file the value supplied by command line argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = args[0];
        try {
            String filePath = "C:/Temp/abc.txt";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
            while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it change when you change the charset of the console window? Which operating system?

Comment: Changing charset of the console window doesn't help. I am using windows 2000

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately you cannot reliably use non-ASCII characters with command-line apps that use the Windows C runtime's stdlib, like Java (and pretty much all non-Windows-specific scripting languages really).

This is because they read their input and output using a locale-specific code page by default, which is never a UTF, unlike every other modern OS which uses UTF-8.

Whilst you can change the code page of a terminal to something else using the `chcp` command, the support for the UTF-8 encoding under `chcp 65001` is broken in a few ways that are likely to trip apps up fatally.

If you only need Japanese you could switch to code page 932 (similar to Shift-JIS) by setting your locale (‘language for non-Unicode applications’ in the Regional settings) to Japan. This will still fail for characters that aren't in that code page though.

If you need to get non-ASCII characters through the command line reliably on Windows, you need to call the Win32 API function `GetCommandLineW` directly to avoid the encode-to-system-code-page layer. Probably you'd want to do that using JNA.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the standard Java launcher has a known and long-living bug in handling Unicode command line arguments on Windows. Maybe on some other platforms too. For Java 7 update 1 it was still in place.

If you feel good at programming in C/C++, you may try writing your own launcher. Some specialized launcher might be not a big deal... Just see the initial example at [JNI Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) page.

Another possibility is to use a combination of a Java wrapper and a temporary file for passing Unicode parameters to a Java app. See my blog [Java, Xalan, Unicode command line arguments...](http://s-n-ushakov.blogspot.com/2011/09/java-xalan-unicode-command-line.html) for more comments and the wrapper code.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8

> With insider build 17035 and the April 2018 update (nominal build 17134) for Windows 10, a "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" checkbox appeared for setting the locale code page to UTF-8

This actually works for me. Without it, no matter what I set `chcp` to or what I supplied as `-Dsun.jnu.encoding`, the argument was always garbled.

I had a test class that would just print the argument that is passed to it:

Before:

```
> java test "üůßβαa"
üußßaa
```

Interesting that with sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, U+03B2 (beta, β) will become a German sharp s (ß) and the Czech ů will become a plain u.

```
> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
> java test "üůßβαa"
uaa
```

Hmm…

```
> java -Dsun.jnu.encoding=utf-8 test "üůßβαa"
?u??aa
```

This is not better. And it becomes worse when CJK characters come into play, for example U+4E80 (亀):

```
> java test "üůßβαa亀"
uaa?
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 6: uaa?
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
        at test.urify(test.java:33)
        at test.urify(test.java:43)
        at test.main(test.java:13)
```

The [class that I used](https://github.com/xproc/Workshop-2018-09/blob/master/p_urify/test.java) not only prints its argument, it also tries to convert it to a file: URI, and it crashed.

Setting the Windows locale to UTF-8 [with the approach quoted above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncXbM.png) solved this issue.

Unfortunately, it didn’t fix encoding issues with arguments passed to another Java program, the XProc processor [XML Calabash](http://xmlcalabash.com/). A sample pipeline that takes a value from the command line and inserts it as an attribute into a document yielded this mojibake:

```
> calabash.bat Untitled3.xpl foo='rαaßβöů亊'
<doc xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" foo="rÎ±aÃŸÎ²Ã¶Å¯äºŠ">Hello world!</doc>
```

Adding `-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8` to the Java invocation fixed this:

```
<doc xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" foo="rαaßβöů亊">Hello world!</doc>
```

For completeness, before switching the Windows locale to UTF-8, depending on whether the code page was 1252 or 65001, the invocation yielded different variations of mojibake that `-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8` couldn’t fix.

So the beta feature to switch the Windows locale finally seems to solve this issue. Some applications might need an additional `-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8`, for reasons not thoroughly researched.

This doesn’t solve your years-old issue with Windows 2000. But maybe you have switched to Windows 10 in the meantime.

Ah, btw, I ran your program and it works with the Windows UTF-8 locale setting.

```
> java test t=r_ä亀
> type C:\Temp\abc.txt
t=r_ä亀
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNA to get that, here's copy-paste from my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class OsNativeWindowsImpl implements OsNative {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OsNativeWindowsImpl.class);

    private Kernel32 kernel32;
    private Shell32 shell32;

    /**
     * This method will try to solve issue when java executable cannot transfer
     * argument in utf encoding. cyrillic languages screws up and application
     * receives ??????? instead of real text
     */
    @Override
    public String[] getCommandLineArguments(String[] fallBackTo) {
        try {
            log.debug("In case we fail fallback would happen to: " + Arrays.toString(fallBackTo));
            String[] ret = getFullCommandLine();
            log.debug("According to Windows API programm was started with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(ret));

            List<String> argsOnly = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
                if (argsOnly != null) {
                    argsOnly.add(ret[i]);
                } else if (ret[i].toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar")) {
                    argsOnly = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            }
            if (argsOnly != null) {
                ret = argsOnly.toArray(new String[0]);
            }

            log.debug("These arguments will be used: " + Arrays.toString(ret));
            return ret;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log.error("Failed to use JNA to get current program command line arguments", t);
            return fallBackTo;
        }
    }

    private String[] getFullCommandLine() {
        try {
            // int pid = kernel32.GetCurrentProcessId();
            IntByReference argc = new IntByReference();
            Pointer argv_ptr = getShell32().CommandLineToArgvW(getKernel32().GetCommandLineW(), argc);
            String[] argv = argv_ptr.getWideStringArray(0, argc.getValue());
            getKernel32().LocalFree(argv_ptr);
            return argv;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get program arguments using JNA", t);
        }
    }

    private Kernel32 getKernel32() {
        if (kernel32 == null) {
            kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
        }
        return kernel32;
    }

    private Shell32 getShell32() {
        if (shell32 == null) {
            shell32 = (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary("shell32", Shell32.class);
        }
        return shell32;
    }

}

interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    int GetCurrentProcessId();

    WString GetCommandLineW();

    Pointer LocalFree(Pointer pointer);
}

interface Shell32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    Pointer CommandLineToArgvW(WString command_line, IntByReference argc);
}
```

In addition to well-known log4j this code also depends on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am able to add jna jar into my project but I am not able to find OsNative in your coding. please help.

Comment: @senderj `OsNative` is just an interface that this class implements, you can create it based on the only public method in this class.

Answer (score 0):

I was having **lots of problems with accents and Java args**, changing the OS locale resolved!

Mob answer did shed some light - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660695/8806187

Example on Linux Debian to **change the locale to pt_BR and charset encoding to ISO-8859-1** (Latin-1 or Windows1252) to accept accents on Java command line arguments:

```
apt update && apt install -y locales
locale-gen pt_BR 
localedef pt_BR -i pt_BR -f ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is because of your system locale. Change your locale to Japanese and it would work.

Here's how to do this http://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

Comment: shouldn't we be able to pass any Unicode value whether Japanese or Korean without changing system locale? Right now don't have resource to do it, will give it a shot.

Comment: This is just a workaround for single language. What if person has more than 1 non-English language on his/her computer? If other applications (like notepad) can handle non-english letters that java application must also be able to do it without changing system locale. See answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/41923480/285060 that will not require to change OS locale

Answer (score -3):

Java works internally with Unicode, so when compiling source code files that used a Chinese encoding such as Big5 or GB2312, you need to specify the encoding to the compiler in order to properly convert it to Unicode.

```
javac -encoding big5 sourcefile.java
```

or

```
javac -encoding gb2312 sourcefile.java
```

Reference: http://www.chinesecomputing.com/programming/java.html

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the question. Question is about invoking application with unicode symbols in args. It is NOT about compiling source code which has unicode symbols in it.