# Characters not correctly transmitted to java from console (cmd) in windows

Tags: java, encoding, cmd, utf-8

I want to run a java class from the command line (cmd) on windows with a parameter (path to a folder) that has utf-8 characters like this:

```
java <MyClass> "mypath/Časdf"
```

This produces the following error message:

> ```
> Could not find the source folder: mypath\Casdf
> ```

As you can see, the first character `Č` has changed to `C`. This also happens with other special characters. I already tried the following:

- change the codepage of the windows cmd to 65001 before executing java
- execute java with option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`
- execute java with PowerShell
- execute java in a Linux environment: no problem there, but I need to be able to execute it in Windows (and preferably with cmd)

Comment: Unsure whether it is a true duplicate, but the answers to [Passing command line unicode argument to Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7660651/3545273) could help

Comment: Hi @SergeBallesta, thanks a lot for the link. It is indeed the same problem there and some helpful answers/explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `dir` inside `cmd.exe` will show the basic latin letter, when the accented letter is not in the console's encoding.

Letting cmd expand an argument `*` will pass the correct string to `main`'s `args`.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\test\\mypath", args[0]);
```

One can also do normal file operations on the path.

My guess is that you are writing a .cmd/.bat file with that file name on a system were the `Č` is not displayable. Then cmd reading the .cmd file will fall back on basic unaccented letters. Also pasting from Windows into a cmd console might not be possible (if you are not in Czechia/Slovakia).

With my charset, "Cp850", I indeed did see `ü` but not `Č` (shown as `C`).

A hard coded path in java needs for instance have the IDE use UTF-8 for the editor and also for the javac compiler.