# Cannot use unicode filename as argument to Java program on Windows cmd, but wildcard works

Tags: java, cmd, unicode, command-line, command-line-arguments

I tried to pass filename with unicode characters to my java program in Windows cmd, but the filename I got in program was broken. Those unicode characters were presented as `?`, and it threw IOException when I read those file.
However, if I use wildcard like `*.txt`, it works correctly.

For example, I have a file called `[テスト]测试文件1.txt` in my directory.
And I wrote a simple java program to show arguments it received, which also prints string bytes.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileArg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String fn: args) {
            System.out.println(fn);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fn.getBytes()));
        }
    }
}
```

My Java version is 15, and I have `chcp` to `65001`, also running program with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` flag.
Then I run `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 FileArg "[テスト]测试文件1.txt" [テスト]测试文件1.txt *.txt`.
The filename is broken if I passed them directly, but it works perfectly with wildcard.

The output:

```
[???]??文件1.txt
[91, 63, 63, 63, 93, 63, 63, -26, -106, -121, -28, -69, -74, 49, 46, 116, 120, 116]
[???]??文件1.txt
[91, 63, 63, 63, 93, 63, 63, -26, -106, -121, -28, -69, -74, 49, 46, 116, 120, 116]
[テスト]测试文件1.txt
[91, -29, -125, -122, -29, -126, -71, -29, -125, -120, 93, -26, -75, -117, -24, -81, -107, -26, -106, -121, -28, -69, -74, 49, 46, 116, 120, 116]
```

Result:
[image: console output]

BTW, my default code page is `cp950` (BIG5).

How could I get it work?

Comment: I suggest reading the comments below the question [How to fix Java args not getting Japanese characters properly in string from Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894485/) I think, you have already read [Passing command line Unicode argument to Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660651/).