# If Windows code page is UTF-8, try to start a Java program with special characters in classpath, results in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, c#, unicode, encoding, command-line-arguments

I am trying to launch a Java program in C# which arguments include Chinese.

```
ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(Javaw);
StartInfo.Arguments = LaunchArgument; //-cp "D:\特殊字符\文件名.jar" com.something.test --arg "特殊字符"
NewProcess.StartInfo = StartInfo;
NewProcess.Start();
```

This is normal if Windows's code page is GBK (Chinese), but if the code page is changed to UTF-8, Java will throw `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.something.test`

In my examination, Java does not seem to be able to properly read Chinese characters in `-cp` when the system code page is UTF-8.

I'v seen [Passing command line unicode argument to Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660651/passing-command-line-unicode-argument-to-java-code/41923480), but there doesn't seem to be a solution using C#.

Modifying the system code page is fine, but requiring users to adjust system settings before using the software is silly...

---

What I've tried:

- Adding `-Dfile.encoding=GBK` or `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the argument.
- Use * to replace Chinese like this, but that doesn't work either.

  `-cp "D:\*\*.jar" com.something.test`
- Use a .bat file and change the code page with the CHCP command at the beginning of it.

```
chcp 936
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3.1\bin\java.exe" -cp "D:\特殊字符\文件名.jar" com.something.test --arg "特殊字符"
```

Also due to the needs of users, there is no way to avoid these Chinese characters in parameters. Sorry.

Comment: Interesting. Out of interest, what does `dir D:\ /ad/x` show you? (Do that in a new cmd.exe - i.e. with its normal code page)